# Auth0 login returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I'm working on a full-stack app with React, express, node, PostgreSQL, and Auth0.
I followed all of the steps for creating a simple login button in react, but when I clicked enter, instead of the Auth0 universal login page, I got https://undefined/authorize?redirect uri=http URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .env file was in the./src directory, which generated this error for me.
I moved it to the app's root, beside the src directory.

What else could be causing this error:

1. There are three fields in your auth0 application settings: Allowed Callback URLs, Allowed Logout URLs, and Allowed Web Origins.
   They must all be set to http://localhost:3000/.
2. Your variable in the.env file must begin with REACT_APP ([docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/))Example:

   REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN=xxxxx

   REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=yyyyy